# Scaling AKS from 1 to 2 nodes: cannot create pods on Node0 and exec (or view logs) on Node1

Tags: azure-container-service

After scaling AKS from 1 to 2 nodes, I got 2 issues.

1. Node0 cannot create new pods. They got stucked at ContainerCreating status.

> Failed create pod sandbox. Error syncing pod.

2. Node1 cannot EXEC and view LOGS:

> the server has asked for the client to provide credentials.

Kubernetes version: 1.8.7

Please advise, thanks!!

---

UPDATE Jun 14, 2018

Issue 1: RESOLVED by restarting the node from Azure Portal and kubectl drain.

Issue 2: NOT RESOLVED.

---

Add some screenshots for Issue 2 (cannot EXEC and LOGS)

[Logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm0vb.png)

[Exec screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlSPB.png)

Comment: This question needs more information. You are not putting any of the commands you are running nor the full errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I updated with some screenshots on kubernetes dashboard.

Comment: I’m sorry, but your “response” images of the dashboard don’t give enough context of what is the command that you are trying to run. Maybe try switching to the cli. It kind of looks like the portal is asking for ssh credentials from your side